# Do these vectors span R^4?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

φ: V —> R^4 is the unique linear transformation with 
φ(v1) = (1,0,0,0) φ(v2) = (1,1,0,0) and φ(v3) = (0,1,1,0). Do these vectors span R^4? V is a 3D vector space over R with basis v1,v2,v3.

The following was my line of working for it.

I multiplied v1 by constant1, v2 by constant 3 and v3 by constant 3 which added together equals a vector (a,b,c,d) so I got (c1, 0,0,0), (c2,c2,0,0) and (0,c3,c3,0) then solved these like a system of linear equations so eventually got c1=a-b+c, c2= b-c abd c3=c. As I therefore got a value for all of the three constants I thought that this meant that the vectors do span R^4? However I wasn’t sure if this makes sense as the last line in the vectors is all 0’s so wasn’t sure what effect this had on it and if it was possible for the vectors to span?

Hope that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: (0,0,0,1) counterexample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to check if something spans a vector space, is to ask yourself if the generating system, you tried to create, can actually span the entire space.

So any vector $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)\in \mathbb R^4$ has to be representable as some linear combination of your vectors.

Since the dimension of your generating system is 3, there has to be some vector in $\mathbb R^4$ has to have no represent. And yes, there is $(0,0,0,1)\in \mathbb R^4$ can't be represented as a linear combination. So your feeling that something is fuzzy was right.

Take away: A vector space of dimension 4 has always a basis of 4 vectors.

Answer (score 5):

Three vectors never span $ \mathbb R^4$, since $ \dim \mathbb R^4 =4.$

Comment: This is a correct answer, but I don't think it helps a lot. Since the contributor ask a basic question about spanning a system, you shouldn't expect them to understand what dimension means. At least give some explanation around it.